# Wordpress Import "File Does not exist" ... But it's there

Tags: wordpress

Pretty much whats in the title. Im using the import feature in wordpress to import from another wordpress. I look in the uploads folder and the xml is uploaded but then the site comes back saying there is no file.

What could be wrong?

It worked the first time once and now trying a second time it will not play ball.

Comment: Just a guess, but try removing the xml file that you have uploaded previously from the uploads folder.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this too. But after the first successfully completed import it deletes it. The next attempt it doesnt and even if I do it wont carry through completely again stating the file just is not there when it is

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with Wordpress that images would say they uploaded, but in fact did not. It seems like you've upgraded your Wordpress installation. Sadly there is no fix for media upload issues due to upgrading Wordpress. It looks like you'll have to backup your site, and import your data in a new Wordpress installation. It's the only way.

If your site's database is bigger than 10MB, you'll have to use Phpmyadmin for that, and change the site address value in the wp_settings table.